# I am stuck at a question and as a beginner in Java it seems overwhelming. Can someone help me understand why exactly my code isn't working?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

```
class Solution {     

    public List<List<Integer>> generate(int numRows) {  

        List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();        
        ArrayList<Integer> row;         
        int v;        
        for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++)         
        {              
            row = new ArrayList<Integer>();             
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)              
            {                  
                if(j==0||j==i)                  
                {                   
                    row.add(1);                 
                    continue;                  
                }                  
                v=l.get(i-1).get(j-1)+l.get(i-1).get(j);            
                row.add(v);              
            }              
            l.addAll(row);         
        }         
        return l;     
    } 
}
```

This is my code and I am confused that why can't I use `addAll()` method to add the collection (`ArrayList`) to the list.

If I replace `addAll()` with `add()` it works fine.

This is a pascals triangle question and logic is correct and have got the correct answer by replacing `addAll()` by `add()` method.

Also this is the error I got:

> error: incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be converted to `Collection<? extends List<Integer>> l.addAll(row);`

I want to know whether we can add an `ArrayList` to a list using `addAll` method.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Additionally, please format your code with conventional indentation - it's *really* hard to read like this. Any IDE should be able to automatically format the code for you. When posting a question, ask yourself: "Would I want to look into helping someone with a question written like this, or is it too hard to understand?"

Comment: Hint: what do you expect `l.addAll(row)` to do? What does the documentation for it suggest? Suppose you `l` were a `List<String>` variable, and `row` were a `String` variable, would you expect to be able to call `l.addAll(row)` in that case, and if so what would you expect it to do?

Comment: I've tried to run your code and I get ` No signature of method: java.lang.Integer.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0]`. This expression doesn't make sense to me: `l.get(i-1).get(j-1)`. `l` is a list of integers, you take integer and tries to get something from it... why?

Comment: addAll() method expect the same type of the source list List<List<Integer>, but you are trying to add List<Integer> using addAll, one way to fix this is use the this code  l.addAll(Collections.singleton(row));

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `addAll()` is to add multiple items to the list. So if you have two lists of the same type and want to copy elements from one to another, you could call `list1.addAll(list2)` instead of having to call `list1.add()` for each element in `list2`.

In this case, the outer list contains elements of type `List`. That means that `addAll()` expects a collection of lists as its argument, but you're only passing a single `List<Integer>`. If your intent is to add that one list to the others in `l`, just use `add()`.